# Getting error in Scrapy DEBUG: Crawled (400)

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to send post request but getting an error. I don't know where I made a mistake. Using FormRequest also doesn't help.

```
class Azadea(scrapy.Spider):
    countries = ["","kw/","lb/","qa/"]
    headers = {
        "POST":"/en/search-store HTTP/2",
        "Host":"www.azadea.com",
        "Accept":"*/*",
        "Accept-Language":"en-US,en;q=0.5",
        "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate, br",
        "Referer":"https://www.azadea.com/en/store-locator",
        "Content-Length":"11",
        "Origin":"https://www.azadea.com",
        "Connection":"keep-alive",
        "Sec-Fetch-Dest":"empty",
        "Sec-Fetch-Mode":"no-cors",
        "Sec-Fetch-Site":"same-origin",
        "Content-Type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
        "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest",
        "Pragma":"no-cache",
        "Cache-Control":"no-cache",
        "TE":"trailers",
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        urls: str = []
        
        for country in Azadea.countries:
            urls.append(f"https://www.azadea.com/{country}en/search-store")       
        
        for url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url=url,
                headers = Azadea.headers,
                method = "POST",
                body = "q=a&start=0",
                callback=self.parse
            )
```

Error Log:

```
2023-03-02 22:44:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
2023-03-02 22:44:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2023-03-02 22:44:31 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://www.azadea.com/en/search-store> (referer: https://www.azadea.com/en/store-locator)
2023-03-02 22:44:31 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://www.azadea.com/en/search-store>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
2023-03-02 22:44:33 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (400) <POST https://www.azadea.com/kw/en/search-store> (referer: https://www.azadea.com/en/store-locator)
2023-03-02 22:44:33 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <400 https://www.azadea.com/kw/en/search-store>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
```

Please let me know where I am making mistakes.

Comment: There are a few issues with your request, but addressing the issues still wouldn't solve the issue because the content is loaded dynamically.

Comment: What are the issues and what can I do to fix and make it work?

Comment: Well it would be helpful if you identified what you goal is.

Comment: The goal is to get the json data from scrapy request. It works in postman but for some reason it doesn't with scrapy standardization

Comment: There are a lot of headers that you probably don't need at all! Without any tests by me, i will probably add a valid and reliable 'User-Agent' to the headers and try again.

Answer (score 1):

`400` means that your request is malformed, and you should fix it.

In this case, the `Content-Length` header from your headers' dict might be causing that. Simply omit it, and Scrapy will fulfill that with the proper value.

Besides, the first header (`POST: ....`) is not how one sets a request as a post. It is being sent as an arbitrary header (e.g. `foo: bar`) and is not helping at all.